# What's The Point of Using Two Classes in One Element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .class1.class2 {
            background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="class1 class2">
            <p>paragraph one</p>
            <p>paragraph two</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Isn't it pointless to use two classes in one element and then style it with multiple class selectors when you can style with one class with a one class selector only? Or is there something that I don't get it ?

Comment: It's not pointless to use two classes in one element. However, it is pointless to style them as per your example.

Comment: Exactly. In this exact situation it makes no sense but in general it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Two of the main arguments for doing so are **reusability** and the **double class selector**. Set up a framework with a set of small CSS classes that can be used in several scenarios. Then apply a combination of them to your elements and, if necessary, apply to a specific element some additional styles that aren't yet covered by the reusable classes.

I'll give a simple example to demonstrate it:

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container.a-super-special-container {
  color: darkgreen;
}

.green {
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This page is divided into several containers.
</div>

<div class="container">
  So let's use a class <i>.container</i> for styling all of them.
</div>

<div class="container a-super-special-container">
  This is a super special container. It builds upon the <i>.container</i> class and colors the text. Instead of copying all the definitions of the <i>.container</i> class we just reuse it.
</div>

<div class="container green">
  As an alternative to the classes used in the previous container we could use two reusable classes <i>.container</i> and <i>.green</i> and apply the styles of both of them.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not pointless.

1. You might want to style `.class1.class2` differently than combined rules of `.class1` and `.class2`.
2. `.class1.class2` selector gives your rule the specificity of 2 classes instead of 1, so that even if your code goes looks like this:

```css
.class1 {
  ...
}
.class2 {
  ...
}
.class1.class2 {
  ...
}
.class3 {
  ...
}
```

... `.class3` value for the prop will not apply on `<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>`, even though it's parsed later by CSS, because the previous selector has greater specificty (of 2 classes), but it will apply to elements with only one of the two classes (i.e. `<div class="class1 class3"></div>`).

It all depends on your use case. Ideally, yes, ***you should limit the use of classes*** (id or any other selectors) as much as possible.

Another rule of thumb in writing quality `CSS` is to limit the specificity of your selectors as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong understanding of the `.` CSS selector.

You can have a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5z2qzwvz/1/):

Here is a small example

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.class1.class2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="class1">
    <p>paragraph one</p>
    <p>paragraph two</p>
  </div>


  <div class="class1 class2">
    <p>paragraph one</p>
    <p>paragraph two</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The first div has only one class i.e `class1` , so the styles of `class1` are applied

The second div has two classes i.e `class1` , and `class2` , so by using `.` selector in the css we can ensure that the element which has both classes only gets styled

If you have `.class1.class2`, what it says is select the elements which have `class1` and also `class2` and apply the style.

Comment: What you have explained was already clear, I think. You didn’t really explain what the code does and why this is useful.

Comment: @Xufox oops sorry , i thought the code was self explainatory, my bad.

Comment: Well, the question is asking why having two classes is useful, so code that uses two classes can’t really be self-explanatory.